# Server-side sorting of posts

Tags: posts, sort

I have seen on some websites that you can sort posts server-side by passing in some queries like so: `domain.com/?sort=date` or `domain.com/?sort=name`

How would I do this with WordPress posts on a page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The display of posts is controlled by WordPress Loop. It has a lot of possible arguments, but they are rarely exposed in URL (especially if using pretty permalinks).

But it is possible to make use of arguments by manually adding them to URL.

For sorting see [Orderby Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Orderby_Parameters). Your example would be something like:

```
domain.com/?orderby=date
domain.com/?orderby=title
```

Comment: Didn't know this was possible on the public side. Can the same be done with number of posts shown? And can the two be mixed together easily, so for example sort them by date and show 20 items.

Comment: Yeah, this is somewhat underknown trick. :) Arguments, related to number of posts, seem to be ignored if used this way. Most probably Loop overwrites them with blog's settings.